# How do you get the margins introduced by a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel **panel** which contains a JTree **tree**. Sometimes the JTree has width or height greater then the panel itself.

What I want to do is recalculate the height and width of tree using the height and width of panel. The only problem is that I don't know how to get the margins introduced by a JPanel in order to precisely calculate the new Size of the JTree.

Example of what i want:

```
if (treeHeight >= panelSize.getHeight()) {
    treeHeight = panelSize.getHeight() - panelMargins; // panelMargins is what I don't know how to calculate
}
```

**UPDATE :**

1. My JTree is **already** in a JScrollPane
2. My JScrollPane is inside the Jpanel

Comment: Put the tree in a [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).  Put the scroll pane in the panel.

Comment: I think you want insets(), but please see @mKorbel answer too.

Comment: You're making it too hard on yourself. Let layouts and borders do the work for you.

Comment: You didn't get my question. I need an explicit way to get the margins introduced by Jpanel when you add child Components to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to use

1) proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

2) add [EmptyBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

then you never need that

Comment: You didn't get my question. I need an explicit way to get the margins introduced by Jpanel when you add child Components to it

Comment: plus I am not allowed to change the LayoutManager

Comment: `You didn't get my question` == most of LayoutManager has implemented gap BorderLayout(10,10), GridLayout(1, 1, 10, 10) etc ...

Comment: but the values can change in the future (with a new java version for example) so I would like to get these values programmatically not manually

Comment: I apology for my rude comments. Your answer helped me find the answer. Thank you